# Node Restify not responding to consecutive requests to the same endpoint

Tags: node.js, restify

I've been playing around with restify and came across a behaviour which I'm having an hard time understanding.

My code is as follows:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var logger = require('log4js').getLogger('index.js');

var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(3000)

var helloCB = function (request, response, next) {

    logger.info('got new request', request.url)
    setTimeout(function () {

        logger.info('sending response', request.url)
        response.send('hello')
        next(false)
    }, 60000)
}


server.get('/hello', helloCB);
```

Now, if I load the following urls by opening **3 browser tabs consecutively with each of the following urls** - in order and without waiting for any response:

> http://localhost:3000/hello
>
> http://localhost:3000/hello
>
> http://localhost:3000/hello?1

Restify seems to be just queueing requests to the same endpoint. The log for my app is as follows:

```
[2015-03-11 14:17:57.601] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:18:02.299] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello?1
[2015-03-11 14:19:57.603] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
```

Please note that the second request is actually logged last and it's logged around 2 minutes after requested.

As a secondary test, I tried to emulate a similar test using ab tool:

> ab -n 5 -c 2 -k http://localhost:3000/hello

I got the following log (this is actually using a smaller timeout for send the response):

```
[2015-03-11 14:23:51.883] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:23:51.887] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:23:57.890] [INFO] index.js - sending response /hello
[2015-03-11 14:23:57.901] [INFO] index.js - sending response /hello
[2015-03-11 14:23:57.902] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:23:57.902] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:24:03.904] [INFO] index.js - sending response /hello
[2015-03-11 14:24:03.905] [INFO] index.js - sending response /hello
[2015-03-11 14:24:03.906] [INFO] index.js - got new request /hello
[2015-03-11 14:24:09.910] [INFO] index.js - sending response /hello
```

Any idea why on the first test the requests to the same endpoint appear to be queued instead of processed immediately?

Thanks

Comment: It could be your browser, or restify, "caching" that the same IP is requesting the same endpoint. I don't know for sure, but I'd guess your browser is waiting until the first comes back before it sends the second. What if you send 3 concurrent cUrl requests? Post back what you figure out.

Comment: Thanks. I've realised that the browser were to able for the delay - maybe a small delay to assess if it can cache the first request and use it for the second or smth. Anyways I've posted an answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation on this I realised the following:

- All requests were actually been performed by the browser (chrome://net-internals/#events)
- The delay in receiving the request wasn't reproducible using curl
- Charles proxy showed that the requests were actually being performed in the order received by restify

So browser to blame. On a side note I was able to reproduce this in FF as well.